# Getting metadata from another database in an sproc in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, metadata

How do I create a stored procedure that exists in one database but runs the below code against another (any) database?

```
SET @sql1 = N'INSERT INTO #Tables SELECT'
          + N' t.TABLE_NAME as TableName'
          + N',t.TABLE_SCHEMA as SchemaName'
          + N',(SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(t.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''.'' + t.TABLE_NAME),''TableHasIdentity'')) '
          + N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDBName) 
          + N'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t'
IF @Verbose = 1
    PRINT @sql1
EXEC(@sql1)
```

I get TABLE_NAME and SCHEMA_NAME successfully, but the main issue is that OBJECTPROPERTY() runs in the context of the stored procedure's database, not in the context of @TargetDBName. So, OBJECTPROPERTY() will always return null, unless @TargetDBName is the same as the database the sproc is in.

I am currently using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the sys views directly like this

```
SELECT  Tbl.name AS TableName, sch.name AS SchemaName,
HasIdentity = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM your_target_db.sys.columns AS cols WHERE Tbl.object_id = cols.object_id and is_identity = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 FROM your_target_db.sys.tables AS Tbl INNER JOIN  your_target_db.sys.schemas AS SCH ON Tbl.schema_id = Sch.schema_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead use OPENQUERY ([see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314520))?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [IDENT_SEED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189834.aspx) in your dynamic query?

This will return the seed value of a table's identity column or NULL if one doesn't exist.

Example:

```
USE master
GO

CREATE DATABASE Test
GO

USE Test
GO

CREATE TABLE Test1 (ColA INT IDENTITY(100,1))
CREATE TABLE Test2 (ColA INT)
GO

USE master
GO

DECLARE @TargetDBName NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TargetDBName = 'Test'

SET @sql1 = N'SELECT' 
          + N' t.TABLE_NAME as TableName' 
          + N',t.TABLE_SCHEMA as SchemaName' 
          + N',(SELECT CASE WHEN IDENT_SEED(''' 
            + QUOTENAME(@TargetDBName) + '.'' 
            + t.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''.'' 
            + t.TABLE_NAME) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HasIdentity ' 
          + N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDBName)  
          + N'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t'  

EXEC(@sql1) 
GO

DROP DATABASE Test
GO
```

The results:

```
TableName  SchemaName  HasIdentity
---------- ----------- -----------
Test1      dbo         1
Test2      dbo         0
```

One caveat you may need to consider:

> Returns NULL on error or if a caller
>   does not have permission to view the
>   object.